# Generate a count variable (by group) if a condition is met in SAS

Tags: foreach, count, sas

For each ID, count the number of times "FAIL" appeared in the QC column, and display that number in the output column (should be generated by the code).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4i5u.png)

```
proc sort data=dataset;
    by ID;
run;
data dataset; 
    set dataset;
        by ID;
        retain count 0;
        if first.qc then count=count+1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two passes through the data to generate the output in your photograph.  One to count and the second to attach the count back onto the individual observations in the group.

You could use PROC SQL because it will automatically re-merge the aggregate statistics back for you.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select *,sum( QC='FAIL' ) as COUNT 
  from have
  group by id
;
```

You could do it with a data step by reading the input twice.  Once to do the count and then again to re-read the observations and write them out.

```
data want;
   do until(last.id);
     set have;
     by id;
     count=sum(count, qc='FAIL' );
   end;
   do until(last.id);
     set have;
     by id;
     output;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: both codes work. I wasn't aware of the count=sum(count, qc='FAIL'); statement in SAS. This is great. Thank you.

Comment: Boolean expressions like `qc='FAIL` will evaluate to 1 or 0. `SUM(,)` function is used in the data step to avoid issues caused by COUNT initializing to missing.  The `SUM()` function used in the SQL code is a different function, the SQL aggregate function, which takes only one argument and sums across observations.